# Hibernate + Spring + persist one-to-one relation + empty foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am trying to persist a one-to-one relation with *Spring 1.2.8* and *Hibernate 3.2.7ga* but the foreign key is always empty.

But let me first give you a short introduction:

I have two Entities called "ClientDomain" (Web-Domain) and "Measurement".

Hibernate Mapping Files:

**ClientDomain.hbm.xml:**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="statistics.jobs.domain">

<class name="ClientDomain" table="domains" lazy="false">

<id column="id" name="id" type="int">
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<property name="version" not-null="false"/>
<property name="url"/>
<property name="etrackerApiUser" column="etracker_api_user"/>
<property name="etrackerApiKey" column="etracker_api_key"/>
<property name="etrackerUsername" column="etracker_username"/>
<property name="etrackerPassword" column="etracker_password"/>

<set 
  name="measurements" 
  table="measurements" 
  lazy="false" 
  cascade="merge,save-update" 
  inverse="true">
  <key column="domain" />
  <one-to-many class="Measurement"/>
</set>   

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Measurement.hbm.xml:**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="statistics.jobs.domain">

<class name="Measurement" table="measurements" lazy="false">

<id column="id" name="id" type="int">
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<property name="version" not-null="false"/>
<property name="time" type="java.util.Date"/>
<property name="numberOfDocuments" column="documents"/>

<one-to-one 
  name="domain" 
  class="ClientDomain" 
  cascade="merge,save-update"
/>   

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am getting some statistics from various source for a domain and then want to persist them. In this way I have a history for a domain.

The ClientDomain objects are already persistent.

A Measurement object is created like so:

```
Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
measurement.setDomain(domain);
measurement.setTime(new Date());
measurement.setNumberOfDocuments(22222);
measurementManager.insertMeasurement(measurement);
```

**insertMeasurement(Measurement measurement):**

```
public void insertMeasurement(Measurement measurement) {    
  getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(measurement);
}
```

This is the result:

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| id | version | documents | time                | domain |
+----+---------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 82 |    NULL |     22222 | 2009-11-16 14:28:32 |   NULL |
| 83 |    NULL |     22222 | 2009-11-16 14:28:33 |   NULL |
| 84 |    NULL |     22222 | 2009-11-16 14:28:34 |   NULL |
+----+---------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
```

I already checked if the domain instance is correct. Everything is as it should be.

So what am I doing wrong? Why is the domain foreign key not saved along with the measurement?

What I tried so far:

- calling persist instead of saveOrUpdate (also changed cascaded to persist)
- wrapping the saveOrUpdate in a session.beginTransaction() and session.getTransaction().commit()

But so far I had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu have a one-to-many relationship from ClientDomain to measurement.  But you have a one-to-one relationship from Measurement to ClientDomain.

Make the relationship in Measurement to ClientDomain a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. Looking back I am a bit angry at myself since this is relativly obvious :(

Comment: Its understandable though, with hibernate it could any number of things, including the obvious and less obvious, I think I spent about 2 days trying to figure out the exact same issue when I was learning, you were smart enough to ask before you spent too much time.  Good luck!